# How to make custom Number list format in word with smart numbering system

Tags: microsoft-word, bookmarks

In my line of work, we deal with documents that are called ASI's (Architectural supplement Instructions). Each ASI is asigned a number in oder from when they are received.  So ASI 01, ASI 02, etc. My question is if there is a way to automate a numbering system to automatically match the ASI number that is located at the top of the page? So the number list would look like this: "A[ASI#].0.1".  I have used a bookmark to link the ASI number at the top of the page with the number located in the footer but I would love to have a list system that works similar to a bookmark and cross reference that updates each time we make a new ASI number.  Is this even possible?
[ASI Sheet Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nn2r3.png)

Comment: Look into the SEQ field and the StyleRef field. Take a look at the field structure of captions.

Comment: So, you want to be able to change the ASI# field at the top right of your document and then use it in numberings with the format "A[ASI#].0.1"? Would only the "1" increment with each heading?

Comment: Loeli, yes.  Only the one would be incremental. I know you can create a custom numbering where you could manually add the ASI number but that is a lot of steps and sometimes we can have hundreds of ASI's so if there is a way to make that automatic would be great!

Also, I will look into the SEQ and StyleRef fields.  I am not sure what those are as I have never needed to sue them before.